# How do you go to a local directory in PuTTy?

Tags: shell, unix, putty

I'm not used to using PuTTy so I'm not very well versed with all the know hows to use it. So after I log onto the HostName/IP address and log in with my username and ID, there's a local directory /u/SysLab/ where one of the file belongs to me and that's where I'm supposed to do my coding, but I'm not sure how to access it, can anyone tell me how to do this? Me googling "How to go to local directory" yields questions that ask how to transfer files to the server, which isn't what I want to do. I just want to go into the directory and start my coding homework. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `cd /u/SysLab`?
That should change your current directory to `/u/SysLab/` after that you should be able to open the file that you want to work on using some editor e.g. if use Emacs then you could do `emacs -nw <yourfile>`.

Comment: Suggesting emacs to someone who doesn't know how to use `cd` is cruel!

Comment: It works! Thank you. Could I also ask you how to copy these files to a directory that I made? I don't want to make changes to these files without having an original copy intact.

Comment: @Adagio — You need to read a basic introduction to the UNIX command line instead of asking Stackoverflow to walk you through every little thing.

Comment: Yes. @Quentin is probably correct. Anyways, you can do `cp <yourfile> <new file location>`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to first get familiar with (at least) some basic navigation and file handling/editing in the terminal before starting to code.

Assuming your OS is Linux/Unix based, `cd` (change directory) and the path should work for you: `cd /u/SysLab`